# Problema ao remover componentes filhos via state em ReactJs

Tags: javascript, array, react, ecmascript-6

Olá!
tenho um código em react que tem como função adicionar ou remover itens de uma lista.
Os itens da lista são componentes filho que vão sendo atualizados a medida que adiciono um novo objeto em um state. Mas ao tentar remover um objeto da lista, ele remove a si próprio e remove também todos os itens seguintes. Por exemplo se há 5 componentes na lista e eu clico no botão do terceiro para remove-lo, ele remove o terceiro, o quarto e o quinto componente da lista, restando apenas o primeiro e o segundo componente. Estou usando a função .filter() e ela está fazendo o trabalho corretamente, mesmo assim o resultado não é o esperado. O que será que estou fazendo errado? Segue o meu código. Obrigado!

Componente pai

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Checkbox from '../components/Checkbox';
import ItemFilho from '../components/ItemFilho';
import SelectSimples from '../components/SelectSimples'

const OpcoesRecomendacoes = ({opcoes, setOpcoes}) => {

  const [itens, setItens] = useState([]);
  const [contador, setContador] = useState(1)
  
  const header = [
    {coluna: "3", nome:"Opções"},
    {coluna: "2", nome:"Subquestão"},
    {coluna: "6", nome:"Recomendação"},
    {coluna: "1", nome:"Ações"}
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(itens);
  }, [itens])

  function handleClick() {
    const opcao = document.getElementById("questao-opcao");
    const subquestao = document.getElementById("ativa-subquestao");
    const recomendacao = document.getElementById("questao-recomendacao");
    setItens([
        ...itens, 
        {
          id:contador,
          key:contador,
          opcao:opcao.options[opcao.selectedIndex].text,
          subquestao:subquestao.checked,
          recomendacao:recomendacao.options[recomendacao.selectedIndex].text
        }
      ])
    setContador(contador+1);
  }

  function handleRemove(id) {
    const newItens = itens.filter(componente => componente.id != id );
    setItens(newItens);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="vstack mb-3">
        <div className="px-3 py-2 bg-light bg-opacity-50 shadow-sm border border-bottom-0">
          <div className="row mb-md-1 mb-3">
            {header.map(({coluna, nome}, indice) => <div className={`col-md-${coluna} col-12`} key={indice}>{nome}</div>)}
          </div>
          <div className="row g-md-none gy-3">
            <div className="col-md-3 col-12">
              <SelectSimples model="opcoes" name="questao-opcao" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2 col-12 align-self-end justify-content-center">
              <Checkbox name="ativa-subquestao" id="ativa-subquestao" />
            </div>   
            <div className="col-md-6 col-12">
              <SelectSimples model="recomendacoes-questoes" name="questao-recomendacao" />
            </div>   
            <div className="col-md-1 col-12 align-self-end">
              <button type='button' className="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" onClick={handleClick}><i className="bi bi-plus"></i></button>
            </div>   
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="list-group shadow-sm rounded-0">
          {itens.map(item => <ItemFilho {...item} handleRemove={handleRemove} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default OpcoesRecomendacoes
```

Componente filho

```
import React from 'react'

const ItemFilho = ({id, opcao,subquestao,recomendacao, handleRemove}) => {

  return (
    <div className={`list-group-item px-3 py-1`} key={id} id={id}>
      <div className="row g-md-none gy-3">
        <div className="col-md-3 col-12 ps-md-4">
          {opcao}
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-2 col-12">
          <input type="checkbox" className='form-check-input' checked={subquestao} readOnly />
        </div>   
        <div className="col-md-6 col-12 ps-md-4">
          {recomendacao}
        </div> 
        <div className="col-md-1 col-12">
          <button type='button' className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm border-0" onClick={() => handleRemove(id)}>
            <i className="bi bi-trash"></i>
          </button>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ItemFilho
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Consegui solucionar!
No componente ItemFilho, passei a função handleRemove fora do spread do objeto adicionado e também no momento de adicionar o objeto na lista de componentes filhos, passei os parâmetros como valores e não objetos. Atualizei o código para aproveitamento.
Obrigado!

Answer (score -4):

Olá, Marco!
Fiz alguns testes aqui com o seu código e está funcionando corretamente. Percebi que você não está importando os hooks do React (useState e useEffect), mas acredito que não seja esse o problema

As únicas partes do código que modifiquei foram os parâmetros "opcao" e "recomendacao", permitindo que a aplicação pudesse rodar aqui, mas nada no sistema de exclusão de itens.

Usei o framework NextJS para fazer o teste, mas acredito que o resultado seja o mesmo usando CRA ou outro template/framework.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Olá, Alex! Obrigado por responder. Eu atualizei a pergunta com os imports que voce mencionou, acho que ficaram de fora quando transferi o código.
Eu havia conseguido solucionar com alterando para o código atual. Obrigado!